# Tem como usar um foreach de uma query dentro de uma função

Tags: php, funções, foreach

Tenho uma *query* simples:

```
$Consulta = $pdo->query(" SELECT * FROM dados ")->fetchAll();
foreach ($Consulta as $key) 
{
     echo $key["InfoDado"];
}
```

Se executar o `foreach` dela fora de uma função! beleza! Funciona como deveria!

Porém tentei executar esse `foreach` dentro de uma função e deu erro!

Tem como executar esse `foreach` dentro de uma função? Algo como:

```
function ExecutarForeach()
{
    foreach ($Consulta as $key) {
        echo $key["InfoDado"];
    }
};

ExecutarForeach();
```

Comment: Você vai ter que passar a variável `$Consulta` para a função. `function ExecutarForeach($Consulta) {...}`

Comment: @stderr Funcionou irmão! Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencionado em [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151038/tem-como-usar-um-foreach-de-uma-query-dentro-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment311807_151038), você pode passar a variável `$consulta` como argumento:

```
function executarForeach($consulta) {
    foreach ($consulta as $key) {
       echo $key["InfoDado"];
    }
}
```

E para chamar a função, faça assim:

```
$consulta = $pdo->query(" SELECT * FROM dados ")->fetchAll();

if ($consulta !== FALSE) {
   executarForeach($consulta);
}
else {
   // Consulta falhou...
}
```

Comment: Bem mais simples do que eu poderia imaginar!